# How to check the log of AOuth login fails on google HWIOAuthBundle/

Tags: symfony, google-developers-console, hwioauthbundle

I am using

HwiOAuthBundle 0.6.3 and symfony 3.4.42

I redirect to google gmail page then select mailaddress and password , but authrization failed and redirect to /fail

Where can I find the log about why google auth failed??

My setting is like this below.

(Before updating symfony2 -> 3, my configuration works correctly)

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
        database:
            entity: { class: UserBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            anonymous: ~
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    google: "/login/check-google"
                    twitter: "/login/check-twitter"
                login_path: /login
                failure_path: /fail
                use_forward: false
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: my.custom.user_provider
            pattern: ^/
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
  #          anonymous: true

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$ 
            security: false
            remember_me:
                secret: "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
                path: /
                domain: ~



hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [secured_area]
    http:
        client: guzzle_client.hwi_special
        message_factory: guzzle_client.message_factory
    connect:
        #account_connector: my_user_provider
        account_connector: my.custom.user_provider
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            facebook: facebook_id
            google: google_id
            twitter: twitter_id
```

---

```
[2019-01-26 00:32:06] request.INFO: Matched route "hwi_oauth_connect_service". {"route":"hwi_oauth_connect_service","route_parameters":{"_controller":"HWI\\Bundle\\OAuthBundle\\Controller\\ConnectController::connectServiceAction","service":"google","_route":"hwi_oauth_connect_service"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/myapp/web/app_dev.php/connect/service/google?code=4%2F3QB2LifyxkqagefM0bc_JL6hLxaNbL7MIGmeP8bB9pCrYzf5oUs9Adc9LceCJCeuc9MrToL2nyxAQ2IzmzWE4D0&scope=email%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&state=6d0b91b9dfbf901aac5f0d81e50155ec","method":"GET"} []
[2019-01-26 00:32:16] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (HWI\\Bundle\\OAuthBundle\\OAuth\\Exception\\HttpTransportException(code: 0): Error while sending HTTP request at /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/vendor/hwi/oauth-bundle/OAuth/ResourceOwner/AbstractResourceOwner.php:266, Http\\Client\\Exception\\NetworkException(code: 0): cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) at /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/vendor/php-http/guzzle6-adapter/src/Promise.php:121, GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException(code: 0): cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) at /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myapp/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:185)"} []
```

Comment: in your `var/logs/app/dev/dev.log` or prod/prod.log you should see sth. like: `security.INFO: Authentication request failed.` with the error_code and message returned by google if you dont you need to adjust the loglevel to info

Comment: Thanks I have found the security.INFO log in log file. I step forward into the problem.